# "Secular person" vs. "secularist"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Would the more appropriate word to describe a person who holds secular beliefs be "secular person" or "secularist"?

Personally, I feel that "secular person" would be the answer as the suffix "-ist" is usually associated with professions (e.g., artist) or followers of theological doctrine (e.g., fundamentalist, Buddhist, Calvinist) whereas secularism is far from following theological doctrine or a denomination.

Comment: "Secularism" doesn't imply that the individual does not adhere to some theological doctrine, but rather that that individual believes that whatever theological doctrines he and his fellow citizens follow should not affect their relationship with their government.

Comment: @HotLicks That is not how the OED defines *secularism*, which is: *The doctrine that morality should be based solely on regard to the well-being of mankind in the present life, to the exclusion of all considerations drawn from belief in God or in a future state.* Note there is no reference to any relationship with government.

Comment: @WS2 - Well, I guess the definition is a religious issue.

Comment: (Try the [National Secular Society (UK)](http://www.secularism.org.uk/what-is-secularism.html).)

Comment: (And the free online Oxford dictionary doesn't define "secularism" at all.  Several other online dictionaries do, with varying definitions, but generally with at least one sense that is "separation of church and state".)

Comment: As to "-ist" meaning someone who adheres to a theological doctrine, I suppose that is true in a way for "leftist" and "rightist".  And, of course, "fetishist".

Comment: I see far less difference between "secular person" and "secularist" than between "human person" and "humanist."

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions  are used and the [-ist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-ist) suffix is also to indicate someone who advocates a belief, as in this case:

[Secularist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/secularist)

> - an advocate of secularism; someone who believes that religion should be excluded from government and education.

(The Free Dictionary)

To avoid confusion I used the expression *secularists are* whose usage  appear to be increasing:

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=secular%20person%2Csecularist%20is%2Csecularists%20%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csecular%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csecularist%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csecularists%20are%3B%2Cc0): *secular person* vs *secularist is* vs *secularists are*

Comment: Whilst this definition accords with the way the National Secular Society defines *secularism* and *secularist*, it is not the meaning given by the OED. See my comment in reply to @Kelvin Zhang's answer.